# Chrome or Firefox extension that fixes Google search links

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

Is there any extension for a browser that allows you to change the structure of links in Google search, so that it doesn't look like this:

```
http://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.intowindows.com%2Fdownload-vlite-for-windows-7%2F&rct=j&q=vlite%20for%20windows%207&ei=mb66TOn4HYumvgP0kPW3DQ&usg=AFQjCNFj7Vo_pgyHyqoCC31j9jpeeJwd-Q&cad=rja
```

I want to copy the address of the result page so that when I right-click and copy the link address, I will only get something like this:

```
http://www.windowsupdatesdownloader.com/
```

Comment: I've found it on makeuseof before but I forgot to bookmark it, and now I can't find it. I think its a userscript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done with a GreaseMonkey script:

- Install [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) if you do not already have it
- Install the [Scrub Google Redirect Links](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/24102) userscript

Afterwards, you will be able to copy URLs directly from the Google search results.

If you are using Google Chrome and do not have (or want to install) Greasemonkey, you may follow these steps instead:

- Visit [Scrub Google Redirect Links](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/24102). Click "Install"
  button. It will download the Javascript file to your computer.
- In Chrome, open Tools -> Extensions. Drag and drop the file you
  downloaded in the previous step to complete installation.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new extension [Google link fixer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-link-fixer/pcpdkhaeeohmogfgcheopfcigcfdaioj) for Chrome/Chromium that does this.

It works by adding a pair of mousedown handlers and prevents the link from being hijacked. Thus it works no matter which way you click the link (either by left/right/middle). The other extension linked by CrazyPotato does not handle the middle click case properly.

[image: Screenshot of the extension from the page]

Comment: @bertieb I have amended the answer

Answer (score 3):

Google/Yandex search link fix 1.4 https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-search-link-fix/

Install Googlebarlite if any problems with Google search bar.  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/googlebar-lite/

Answer (score 3):

There is a Chrome Extension to do this: [Remove Google Redirection](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remove-google-redirection/dnhjklgpiifbofihffldllbcopkinlod)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Firefox extension to do this: [Google Redirects Fixer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-no-tracking-url/)

Comment: This sort of works for me, but not totally correctly. I have to do "Copy link location" twice; only after the second time do I get the cleaned-up URL.

Comment: I didn't notice that until you pointed it out. To be fair to the author, he explains why it works that way in the comments. I also noticed that he does say that if you copy the URL into a new tab then this addon will intercept the URL and change it to the correct one before the network request is made.

Answer (score -2):

You can right-click the Omnibar and select 'Edit search engines...' to change what your search URLs look like. A simple Google search looks like this: http://www.google.com/search?q=%s

Comment: This is completely irrelevant to the question.